# string concat in c#?

Tags: asp.net

what is different between string `+`, `string.concat()`;

i mean

```
string a="sasi", string b="surya";
```

`string x= a+b`, and `string x= string.concat(a,b);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. The plus (+) operator compiles to a string.concat method; see [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/johnsperfblog/archive/2005/05/27/40777.aspx) and [here](http://dotnetperls.com/string-concat).

Newer versions of the compiler optimize the usage of the (+) operator anyways, so they are equally efficient.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, nothing, really. However, `string.Concat()` can also be used to:

- Concatenate an array of strings (`string.Concat(string[])`)
- Concatenate the string representations of an array of objects (`string.Concat(object[])`)
- Concatenate an `IEnumerable<T>` of strings

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx) for the full overload list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see a performance benchmark check [this post from Jeff](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)

Comment: Not relative to the question - but helpful

Answer (score 0):

Concat performs 1 concatination regardless of how many strings are provided so has better performance over the + operaton. http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/03/16/concatperf